# Computer will not boot up

Tags: motherboard

My grandson switched the computer on and said it made a noise, I checked the fuse in the plug it had blown I replaced it but when switched on there was a bang and when I checked the PSU had blown I replaced it and tried to boot it without the monitor it did one beep so I switch it off using the computer button but I then tried it again and it did not start when the computer button is pressed the all the fans start but when I let go the button everything stops, if I hold the button in the fans speed up and slow down until I let go and then they stop. If I replace the motherboard, will that solve the problem as that would me the original cause of the short would be the m/board?

```
AMD PHENOM II X4 955 (3.20GHz/8MB CACHE/AM3) - BLACK EDITION    
ASUS® M4A87TD/USB3: DUAL DDR3,SATA 6.0GB/s, USB 3.0 
4GB SAMSUNG DDR3 DUAL-DDR3 1333MHz (2 X 2GB)    
1GB ATI RADEON™ HD 5750 PCI EXPRESS - DirectX® 11
```

Comment: Is the wattage of the new PSU more than the old one?

Comment: I would first remove the video card and make sure it wasn't just the video card that was damaged. If removing the video card does not solve anything, more than likely replacing the motherboard will solve the issue. I've fixed a few computers that have gone through power surges. Most of the time, the PC's will boot up and have the fans spinning, just like in your scenario. In those instanced, I did replace the motherboard and all was well after doing so. I would say it is not a 100% guaranteed fix though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The PSU is the power supply unit and while I can build a basic computer I do not have a voltmeter or resistance-meter.

Comment: I am trying to calculate what is the best option replace the motherboard  which would be cheaper than buying another computer but if that did not resolve the problem I would have wasted the cost of the m/board and still have to buy a new computer.

Comment: It's not possible for us to say if you should replace the computer or replace components.  What has happen is your current computer has failed electrical dealing with relatively a lot of wattage/amperage/voltage it could be solved by a new motherboard or that will just be one of several issues.  You have extremely out dated hardware replacement hardware will be expensive

Answer (score -1):

Sir I will suggest you to replace the RAM. The issue which you are stating is very common.

As you already mentioned above that you have 2 RAM stick of 2GB Each.
I will suggest you to use one RAM and remove the other on than try to boot your system up and after that try remove the other RAM and insert the other RAM.

Best of luck

Comment: Solved the problem - I bought a new power suppy unit and removed or disconnected everything except the video card  because there is no video on the motherboard and removed one of the 2 sticks of memory switched on and the bios booted I then added one component or disc drive and tested after each addition. I don't know the exact fault but when I connected the IDE cable it failed to boot the cable was attached to a zip drive I don't use.  Thanks for the suggestions